# SQL Query Buffer in result - Show one by one

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlresultsetmapping

I have a sql script as follow :

```
declare db_list cursor  for
select name From sys.databases
open db_list 
declare @var varchar(MAX)
fetch next from db_list into @var
print @var
while (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
    BEGIN
        EXEC('use '+@var)
        print 'Checking database '+@var
        print '---------------------------------------------'
        dbcc checkdb
        fetch next from db_list into @var
    END
close db_list
deallocate db_list
```

I wish to get the result one by one.
For instance, when @var is set to 'master'. It should show :

```
Checking database master
```

and then it should show 'dbcc checkdb' result for master.

Instead the result hangs for undefined time and then suddenly displays all results for all databases. 
I am using MS SQL Server 2008 for this.

Comment: What is the main problem? You trying to call dbcc checkdb not for current database or print results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Dan Guzman said, you can use `RAISERROR`.
However, you cannot `EXEC('use '+@var)` and later use `dbcc checkdb`. These two statements are executed in different batches, so the dbcc is always executed on your current connection. Try the following, it worked for me (sql server 2012/2014). I also changed the cursor a bit to exclude Microsoft owned tables (Master, Model etc). If you do want those checked, you know what to do :P.

```
DECLARE @text NVARCHAR(100) = 'Checking database '
,       @ErrorText NVARCHAR(100)
,       @var varchar(MAX)

declare db_list cursor  FOR
select name From sys.databases
WHERE owner_sid <> 0x01
open db_list 

fetch next from db_list into @var
print @var
while (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
    BEGIN
        SET @ErrorText = @text + @var
        RAISERROR(@ErrorText, 0, 0) WITH NOWAIT
        RAISERROR('---------------------------------------------', 0, 0) WITH NOWAIT
        EXEC('use ' + @var + '; dbcc checkdb')
        fetch next from db_list into @var
    END
close db_list
deallocate db_list
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I refined the answer to following code as your code made sql skip all databases. Since owner_sid is same for all in my case.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid buffering results, you can use `RAISERROR...WITH NOWAIT` with severity 0 to generate an info message:

```
RAISERROR ('Checking database %s', 0, 0, @var) WITH NOWAIT;
```

If there are preceding buffered results, such as from DBCC output, those will also be flushed by the `RAISERROR...WITH NOWAIT`.

Comment: Will it show dbcc result for one database and then jump to another? instead of showing all dbcc checkdb result at once. ???

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use it not for current database, try to do this:

```
exec('dbcc checkdb (' + @var + ', NOINDEX)')
```

Comment: Thanks but that gives output all at once. Still thanks for your valuable answer.